# Does the SmartHealthIt or Cerner SMART on FHIR sandbox support write operations?

Tags: smart-on-fhir

I'm working on testing SMART on FHIR applications, specifically the asbi screening application here: https://github.com/asbi-cds-tools/asbi-screening-app .

I'm able to get the app to run locally and I can test the app using the SmartHealthIt testing tool here: https://launch.smarthealthit.org/ .

The application runs and I am able to complete the questionnaire.  When I hit the final submit button everything seems to complete without error.

However, none of the survey data seem to be written to the patient record.

Does the https://launch.smarthealthit.org/ support writing data from the SMART on FHIR application being tested? Is there an example application that does this?

Does the Cerner application (https://code.cerner.com/developer/smart-on-fhir/apps) support writing patient data from a SMART on FHIR application? Is there an example application that demonstrates this?

Is there a different sandbox that supports this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The SMART App Launcher is a simulator to replicate the process of launching a SMART on FHIR app. Whether writing data is permitted ultimately comes down to whether the FHIR server accepts writing operations like create and update. Per the [CapabilityStatement](https://r4.smarthealthit.org/metadata), the SMART R4 open endpoint does for various resources. Cerner, Epic, and support writing operations as well. Your best bet is likely to review the documentation for the sandbox(es) you're interested in and determine what capabilities are available that align with your desired workflow.